# SEOstats API Google Pagerank Blocked by Google

Tags: api, seo, statistics

I wrote a php script to get all the urls' pageranks of my company website.  But get the following response from GetWithCurl($url) - $str.  It looks like  Google has some restriction to get the pagerank dynamically.

Is there any way to resolve it?  or contact with google?  but how.  Thank you!

---

Sorry...**Google**Sorry...

## We're sorry...

... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

See [Google Help](http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=86640) for more information.
© 2009 Google - [Google Home](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. That is not an issue with SEOstats. The problem is that Google detected that you send automated requests to it, which is against their Terms of Services!

You should be able to "solve" this by getting a fresh IP from your provider (turn router off/on) or sending your requests through proxies. **Anyway, you must decrease your request frequency to avoid getting blocked again**!

See: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/issues/33